# Is there a limitation in AWS to open an IPSec VPN connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devsecops, vpn

Consider the following situation (for test purposes):

- there is a public IPSec VPN endpoint (StrongSwan);
- a machine with either Ubuntu (Strong Swan client) or Windows OS (native client) running in the cloud should be the VPN guest.

Result:

- Windows Server 2019 machine establishes VPN connection successfully but can't send any packet
- Ubuntu 18 machine establishes connection to some degree but does not create PPP0 interface.
- Ubuntu 16 machine makes a handshake but then there is a message about protocol mismatch (maybe in this specific case there is an incompatibility between both endpoints).

Are there any AWS limitations to IPSec VPN?

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks to be tunnel misconfigured -  "there is a message about protocol mismatch"

Regarding the limitations quick google took me here: [[strongSwan] strongswan limits](https://lists.strongswan.org/pipermail/users/2010-December/001179.html)